# Write.csv for large matrix

Tags: r, class, csv, matrix, typeof

I am using R for some long calculations. I have parallelised my code to be able to use it more efficiently on a cluster and output the results (a matrix of numbers) using `write.csv()`.

Once I get the results, I analyse them on my laptop using `read.csv()`.
Since the file I output is a matrix of double, I expect that it still is once I use `read.csv()` but not always...

I noticed (although not sure if it's why), if my matrix is "small" (dim = 6x50), then the matrix is of type double.
However when I output big matrices (dim = 128x10⁴), it is a character!

I have :

`typeof(small matrix) = "double"`
`class(small matrix) = "matrix"`
`typeof(big matrix) = "character"`
`class(big matrix) = "matrix"`

I am using exactly the same code for both apart from outputting matrices of different sizes.
If you need any other details, please ask.

EDIT : I just realised the last time I ran the code it did not even output a file when I was calculating a big matrix. It did all the calculations though. Is it possible there's something I'm not doing properly with `write.csv`?

`write.csv(Output, file = "Output.txt")`

Comment: Have you considered using save/load for this, it skips the inconvenient conversion of the data into a human readable form, so should be less prone to problems.

Comment: I didn't, will check it now.

Comment: As Miff proposed, you should use saveRDS() and readRDS().

Comment: Seems to work fine on small matrices, will need to calculate the big one and try. @KarlForner &Miff, any idea what happens with write.csv though? I would like to understand.

Comment: difficult to say w/o looking at the matrices. Once saved as rds files, you can have a look at the exact object to see if there are differences (so before the write.csv). Because you assume that it is write.csv() that modifies the columns, but maybe not.

Comment: @KarlForner : `saveRDS` on a big matrix made something strange. The matrix was supposed to be 128x10⁴ but when I load it it's 49858x0. I really don't get it :-s

Comment: it may be the problem: your matrix is not  what you think.

Comment: Solved this issue. I was was using `read.csv`, forgot to change it to `readRDS`. Thanks, all works smoothly and much smaller files as well : 20MB -> 2MB